# Running Laravel with Docker and Apache gives me 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, laravel, docker, apache

I am working on Laravel project and it works fine locally but I am trying to setup `Docker`  so it is easier to deploy. However, I keep getting the `403 Forbidden` error when trying to access the website through the `Docker` instance. I've searched on the internet for solution but everything seems fine. I've set the permissions to `777` just to see if it will work but no luck there. The user and group that own the files inside the `Docker` instance are `application:www-data`. I've enabled `mod-rewrite`.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache:8.2

EXPOSE 80

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg && mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
RUN NODE_MAJOR=18 && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN a2enmod rewrite 

WORKDIR /var/www/zavoon.com

CMD bash -c "service apache2 restart && composer install --no-dev && npm install && npm run build && php artisan migrate && supervisorctl start 'zavoon-com:*' && apachectl -D FOREGROUND"
```

here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-apache:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: main
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/zavoon.com
      - ./docker/supervisor/zavoon.com.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zavoon.com.conf
      - ./docker/apache/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    ports:
      - 8003:80
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: unless-stopped
```

here is my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@email.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/zavoon.com/public

        ErrorLog /docker.stderr
        CustomLog /docker.stdout combined

        <Directory /var/www/zavoon.com/public>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
                ReWriteEngine On
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've messed around with the virtual host file a lot but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if /var/www/zavoon.com is readable by the user running apache process, it is root? what user it is?

Comment: not only readable but writable too

Comment: are you using `localhost:8003`? or what url are you using?

Comment: @HernanGarcia there are three `Apache` processes when running `top` one run by root and the other two by `www-data`. Site files are readable and writable.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I am using `zavoon.local:8003`. I've configured `zavoon.local` to point to localhost.